# When did the term "mirror" begin to be used in place of "looking glass?"

Tags: united-states, terminology

As recently as 150 years ago (I'm thinking of Lewis Carrol's "Through the *Looking Glass*"), the term *looking glass* was used to denote what we today call a mirror.

I'm wondering, however, when the transition between these two words occurred, and I can't seem to find any historical sources for this. Could someone help me?

Comment: Historically mirrors were primarily made of metal until flat glass mirrors were introduced about 500 years ago.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [English Language & Usage StackExchange.](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It didn't.

The word [mirror](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mirror) (First Known Use: 13th century) predates 
the phrase [looking glass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/looking+glass) by several hundred years(First Known Use of looking glass
1562).  Just different words for the same thing.

If you do a google book search and set the publication date to pre-[Through the Looking Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass)(1871) you will find a publications dating to 1776 [with  *Mirror* in the title.](https://books.google.com/books?id=D5UDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA74&dq=mirror&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQn_S2orTRAhUY7GMKHaujCEAQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=mirror&f=false).

Comment: Note, however, that a "glass" could also denote a mirror, and that this usage also dates back to the 13th century ([according to the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/78752#eid2970373) — behind a paywall, sorry.)